# How to scale a very short expiry of auth_token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, memcached, redis, scalability

I'm using Mongodb to store users' data, including the user status (online|offline|busy). The expiry time is just a few seconds. If a user doesn't show up (send keepalive request) after a few seconds, I want to set the status to offline.

I'm looking for a scalable solution for this. I was thinking about adding 'lastseen' attribute and to run a cron job to update the statuses, but I think it's not scalable.

Is there a better way to do this? How can I use Redis or Memcashed to help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TTL collection. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/

One technique that would work is to have a collection of sessions with a last_seen timestamp. The TTL collection would be configured to delete sessions once the last_seen timestamp was more than X seconds ago. As long as a session is online, you'd periodically refresh the last_seen timestamp to prevent it from being cleaned up.

Example:

1. Setup the TTL collection:

   db.sessions.ensureIndex( { last_seen:1 },{ expireAfterSeconds: 60 } );
2. Ping to keep a session alive (or create it if it wasn't there already)

   db.sessions.update( {_id: , last_seen:  }, { upsert:true } );
3. Query to see if a user is online:

   session = db.sessions.find( { _id:  } )

   - if returns a document, then the user is online
   - if no document returns, then they are offline

Comment: I have 'busy' status as well, unfortunately I think this solution will not work in this situation.

Comment: @Amer: Then you could just add a status to the sessions collection, alternatively a `busy` flag. It seems like a good approach. You could model this in redis with [EXPIRE](http://redis.io/commands/expire), but @jared's solution is preferable since you're already on mongo.